# Peewee Model, dicts()

Tags: python-3.x, orm, peewee

I'm debugging existing code. I'm trying to find out the intention of the obviously wrong access to `.dicts` of a peewee `Model` in the `warning` statement in `MyDbBackend.store` and how I could correct that.
I guess that the warning message should add more detailed output to the model which could not be saved. However, the `.dicts` attribute exists in `orm.BaseQuery` class, only.

The output message is currently not very helpful. I want to provide an improved warning message given that the `i.save` fails. With "improved" i mean to provide some meta informations about the record which failed to be saved.

So, how can i obtain the `BaseQuery` from the `model` and what would `.dicts` output, then? Would that information be useful in the context of the warning message?

```
import peewee as orm


database = orm.Proxy()


class ModelBase(orm.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database


class MyModel(ModelBase):
    dtfield             = orm.DateTimeField(null=True)
    intfield            = orm.IntegerField(null=True)
    floatfield          = orm.FloatField(null=True)


class MyDbBackend:
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.db = database
        self.records = []  # Holds objects derived from ModelBase

    [...]

    def store(self):
        with self.db.atomic():
            for i in self.records:
                try:
                    i.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.warning("could not save record: {}".format(i.dicts()))
                    raise e

        self.clear()
```

->

```
logger.warning("could not save record: {}".format(i.dicts()))
AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'dicts'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the original code was meant to make use of `playhouse.shortcuts.model_to_dict`.
This is the only idea I have why the original code uses `i.dict()`.
Perhaps some misunderstanding.

```
import peewee as orm
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict

[...]

logger.warning(f"Model dict: {model_to_dict(i, recurse = True, max_depth = 2)}")
[...]
```